# postgreSQL - Checking if one date interval does not overlap a date interval in array of intervals for each row

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

PostgreSQL(9.6), I am trying to check whether a date interval

```
('2018-11-18 12:00','2018-11-20 12:00')
```

does not overlap any of the following date intervals in the array

```
{('2018-11-21 12:00','2018-11-23 12:00'),('2018-11-19 12:00','2018-11-20 12:00')}
```

The elements in the array are composite:

```
CREATE TYPE reservation AS (
    checkIn TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    checkOut TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
)
```

Here is the rooms table:

```
CREATE TABLE rooms (
rId roomId PRIMARY KEY,
hRef hotelId NOT NULL,
rNo roomNo NOT NULL,
rType roomType,
numPeople INTEGER,
rBedOptions roomBed[],
reservations reservation[],
priceNight FLOAT,
FOREIGN KEY (hRef) REFERENCES hotels(hId) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL  
)

INSERT INTO rooms VALUES
('R001','H001','101','one-bedroom',1,
ARRAY[row('1 twin')::roomBed],
ARRAY[
      row('2018-11-21 12:00','2018-11-23 12:00')::reservation,
      row('2018-11-19 12:00','2018-11-20 12:00')::reservation],
450.5);
```

Basically I am trying to check whether a "room" is available for a selected time interval by checking if this interval does not overlap with any existing reservation date intervals ('2018-11-21 12:00','2018-11-23 12:00'),('2018-11-19 12:00','2018-11-20 12:00'). So far I have been successful in checking the first element of the array for each row by writing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms R 
WHERE R.reservations[1] IS null 
OR NOT (('2018-11-18 12:00','2018-11-20 12:00') 
OVERLAPS (R.reservations[1].checkIn, R.reservations[1].checkOut)) 
ORDER BY rid;
```

The problem is that I don't know how to check all elements in the array if there is more than one. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to save nested structures like arrays within a table? Why not use a join table in long format? I usually recommend to OPs not using multiple items within tables and data sets (e.g., Python, R). Save bit data points in columns in long row tables. Otherwise querying will be very complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can use `unnest` to transform array into row on the fly

```
SELECT * 
  FROM rooms R,
    LATERAL (SELECT bool_or(
                        ('2018-11-18 12:00','2018-11-20 12:00') 
                       OVERLAPS (periods.checkIn, periods.checkOut)
                   ) as someone_overlaps
              FROM unnest(R.reservations) periods
             ) ok
  WHERE someone_overlaps is not true
  ORDER BY rid;
```

### Explain

1. For each row in this sentence you do a "Lateral" subselect to ask if it overlaps
2. Unnest array into several rows
3. Check the overlaps
4. Compute the `OR` of each overlap, take it in the `someone_overlapas`
5. List each row that not have `someone_overlapas`

### Notes

- Booleans in postgress have three states: `true`, `false` and `null` thats why is not the same `not someone_overlaps` that `someone_overlaps is not true`, in the first case the `null` value remains `null` in the seconds `null is not true`. The second is used because the reservations may be an empty array.
- `Lateral` a keyword that allows to use previous tables (in the from list) to be used in the curren subselct
- `unnest` a function that transforms array into row
- you can see a living example at: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c070f0eeaf4206f0540d9187c5e874d3